# Lifting up state in React

Tags: reactjs, state, lifting

say i have this React Class. This is NOT my main component that I'm rendering. how can i pass the state i set in here UPWARDS to the parent component.

```
class Player extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          playerOneName: ''
        }
        this.selectPlayerOne = this.selectPlayerOne.bind(this);
      }

      selectPlayerOne(e, data) {
        this.setState({playerOneName: data.value})
      }

      render() {
        let players = [];
        this.props.players.map((player) => {
          players.push({text: player.name, value: player.name})
        })

        return (
          <div className="playersContainer">
            <div className="players">
              <Dropdown onChange={this.selectPlayerOne} placeholder='Select Player One' fluid selection options={players} />
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

when I say parent component i mean the class that is going to display player like so:

```
<Player />
```

I.e. how can I make this.state.playerOneName available to the parent?

Comment: React is unidirectional by nature. You cannot or I should say you should not pass state from chil to parent. For this your must make use of redux or flux.

Comment: @ShubhamJain what is lifting state up all about then?

Comment: @TheWalrus This part `onChange={this.selectPlayerOne}` is what you need to change, you should pass the on change callback as a property from the parent.

Comment: This has better insights https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 1):

Hey so the point here is that you are basically passing in, from your parent component into your child component, a prop which is a function.

In parent:

```
handler(newValue){ 
    this.setState({key: newValue}) 
}
render() {
    return(
        <Child propName={handler.bind(this)}>
    )
}
```

When a change takes place in your child component, you call the function and pass in the new value as an input. This way you are calling the function in your child component, and making a change to the state of the parent component.

In your case you want to, instead of setting the state of playerOneName, pass in a function from the parent of this class and do something like `this.props.functionFromParent(playerOneName)` in your 'selectPlayOne' function.

It is true that the flux pattern is unidirectional, however when you're dealing with smart and dumb components you will see that data is passed from a dumb component to a smart component in this way. It is perfectly acceptable React form!

Answer (score 0):

"Lifting state up" for *React* means that you should replace data from your child component to parent component state and pass data for presentation to child component by props.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to achieve your goal. Create a parent component which hold `playerOneName` as its state. Pass it as a prop to child component and with that also a function that changes the `playerOneName` whenever it is changed in the child component.

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
     this.state = {
      playerOneName: ''
     }
  }
  render() {
      return(
          <Child 
              playerOneName={this.state.playerOneName}
              onPlayerOneNameChange={(playerOneName) => this.setState({playerOneName})}
         />
      );
  }
}
```

Use this function like this in child component to change the name of `playerOneName` in Parent component, like this your child component is only displaying the value of the `playerOneName` all the changes are done in Parent component only.

```
class Child = props => {
  const { playerOneName, onPlayerOneNameChange } = props;
  return (
     <TextInput 
       value={playerOneName}
       onChangeText={(playerOneName) => onPlayerOneNameChange(playerOneName)}
     />
  );
}
```

By this you can use updated `playerOneName` in your Parent component whenever you like by using `this.state.playerOneName`